# SDL2 on Mac segmentation fault and memory error

Tags: python, c, macos, sdl-2

I'm writing a very basic code in C that is supposed to read the name of a joystick plugged via USB.

When I execute the code, sometimes it works and shows the name of the joystick, some other times it fails with a segmentation fault. Nothing changes from one run to another.

I also tried with a Python application and I also get memory errors.

The same software perfectly works, all the time, on Ubuntu.

The C code is the following

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main()
{
    // Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK) != 0)
    {
        printf("SDL initialization failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Check for available joysticks
    int numJoysticks = SDL_NumJoysticks();
    if (numJoysticks <= 0)
    {
        printf("No joysticks found.\n");
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the first joystick
    SDL_Joystick* joystick = SDL_JoystickOpen(0);
    if (joystick == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open joystick: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    // Print joystick information
    printf("Joystick Name: %s\n", SDL_JoystickName(joystick));

    // Close the joystick and quit SDL
    SDL_JoystickClose(joystick);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

The python code I tried is:

```py
import pygame
import sys

# Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# Initialize joystick
pygame.joystick.init()

# Check for available joysticks
num_joysticks = pygame.joystick.get_count()
if num_joysticks == 0:
    print("No joysticks found.")
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

# Initialize the first joystick
joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
joystick.init()

# Get and print joystick name
joystick_name = joystick.get_name()
print("Joystick Name:", joystick_name)

# Main loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

# Clean up
joystick.quit()
pygame.quit()

sys.exit()
```

The errors I find are (they change from one run to another):

- Segmentation fault: 11
- C:

  ```
  test_joystick(33320,0x114cc2e00) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fe526f18ae0: probably modified after being freed.
  Corrupt value: 0x9000ff008087f1fc
  test_joystick(33320,0x114cc2e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
  Abort trap: 6
  ```
- Python:

  ```
  Python(32994,0x108c72e00) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7faef19c02e0: probably modified after being freed.
  Corrupt value: 0x3000ff008087f1fc
  Python(32994,0x108c72e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
  Abort trap: 6
  ```

I have installed SDL2 two times: one via brew install, and the other one via the github repository. Nothing changed.
In the past, the same code worked also on macOS, I know it for sure.

Do you have any idea about how to fix it?

I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.6.8.